# Docker container live migration in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, migration

I am searching for a tutorial or a good reference to perform docker container live migration in Kubernetes between two hosts (embedded devices - arm64 architecture).

As far as I searched on the internet resources, I could not find a complete documentation about it. I am a newbe and it will be really helpful if someone could provide me any good reference materials so that I can improve myself.

Comment: In Kubernetes, you don't usually do any sort of live migration.  A Pod is usually managed by a Deployment; if you delete a Pod, the Deployment will create a new one; and if you change the Deployment (to update its image, for example) it will delete and recreate the existing Pods.  "Delete and recreate" might not be on the same node, and this is also how adding or removing nodes from the cluster is handled.

Comment: suppose if i need to move the running container(application) from one cluster to other cluster. I need to checkpoint from one one node(in one cluster) and restore it in one node(in another cluster). In that case, they should share the same volume.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

As @David Maze said in terms of containers and pods, it's not really a live migration. Usually pods are managed by `deployments` which have `replicasets` which control pods state: they are created and in requested amount. Any changes in amount of pods (e.g. you delete it) or using image will trigger pods recreation.

This also can be used for scheduling pods on different nodes when for instance you need to perform maintenance on the node or remove/add one.

---

As for your question in comments, it's not necessarily the same volume as it can I suppose have a short downtime.

Sharing volumes between kubernetes clusters on premise (cloud may differ) is not a built-in feature. You may want to look at `nfs` server deployed in your network:

[Mounting external NFS share to pods](https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-nfs-persistent-volume-kubernetes/)